# No module named 'azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2019_08_01'

Tags: azure, centos7, azure-aks, az

I am getting an error while working with **Azure CLI** az. I am using azure version of `2.0.80`. and I am using **CentOS 7**. When I run az command `az aks update` i am getting error like

> The command failed with an unexpected error. Here is the traceback:
>
> No module named 'azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2019_08_01' Traceback
>   (most recent call last):
>
> File
>   "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/cli.py", line 206, in 
>   invoke
>       cmd_result = self.invocation.execute(args)   File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
>   line 528, in execute
>       self.commands_loader.load_arguments(command)   File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/**init**.py",
>   line 299, in load_arguments
>       self.command_table[command].load_arguments()  # this loads the arguments via reflection   File
>   "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/commands/**init**.py",
>   line 291, in load_arguments
>       super(AzCliCommand, self).load_arguments()   File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/knack/commands.py", line
>   97, in load_arguments
>       cmd_args = self.arguments_loader()   File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/**init**.py",
>   line 496, in default_arguments_loader
>       op = handler or self.get_op_handler(operation, operation_group=kwargs.get('operation_group'))   File
>   "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/core/**init**.py",
>   line 536, in get_op_handler
>       op = import_module(mod_to_import)   File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/importlib/**init**.py", line 126, in
>   import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)   File "", line 994, in _gcd_import   File
>   "", line 971, in _find_and_load   File
>   "", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked 
>   File "", line 665, in _load_unlocked
>   File "", line 678, in
>   exec_module   File "", line 219, in
>   _call_with_frames_removed   File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/custom.py",
>   line 29, in 
>       from ._helpers import _populate_api_server_access_profile, _set_load_balancer_sku, _set_vm_set_type   File "/usr/lib64/az/lib/python3.6/site-packages/azure/cli/command_modules/acs/_helpers.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2019_08_01.models import ManagedClusterAPIServerAccessProfile ModuleNotFoundError: No module
>   named 'azure.mgmt.containerservice.v2019_08_01'